# Custom Post Type Templates In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I don't suppose anyone is aware of whether custom post types can have custom templates just like posts in WP?  I've found no documentation on this on the codex and can't really find any relevant material.  I'd have assumed WP 3.1 supports this but there's no mention to it.  It seems like a black hole that someone must know about?

Apologies for the very generic, open-ended question.  I know about custom post types and have implemented them, it's just this seems undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "templates"? Are you using the term in the same way WP defines it? If so, they seem to be supported: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types

> In the form of the
>   single-type-template. In the same way
>   that posts are shown on their own page
>   with single.php, custom post types
>   will use single-{posttype}.php if it's
>   available.

Comment: Yes, for single and archives this works, but for templates other than this.  For pages, for example, you can select a drop-down list on the right-hand side of the WP admin interface as to what "Template" you want to use.  I want the exact same functionality for custom post types.  See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates